# IBOutletCollection NSMutable Array order in IB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have linked a set of buttons to and IBOutletCollection NSMutableArray;
I want to be able to make each button play a specific sound;
However after linking them I realised they were not added in any particular order. 
I think the interface builder doesn't take into account the order of the added buttons.
Is there any way I could possibly access the interface button id through code and cast it as an integer so I could programatically assign the right sound to the right button?

Don't think is necessary but here is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<48;i++){
UIButton *Pad=[UIButton alloc];
[Pads addobject:Pad];
[Pad release];
[[Pads objectAtindex:i] addTarget:self action:@selector(play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
((UIButton*)[Pads objectAtIndex:i]).tag=i;
}
```

To be more specific. In the interface builder in the atributes inspector each button has a label and an id. Would it be possible to reorder my array programatically using that id(or label for that matter)?

FIXE by sorting by TITLE [button currentTitle]

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the `tag` property of each IBOutlet to `i` when adding it to `Pads`.

Answer (score 2):

IBOutletCollection do not support ordering. Here's a similar question with an answer which orders collection contents by their position:
[IBOutletCollection set ordering in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527762/iboutletcollection-set-ordering-in-interface-builder)