# xcode array access with IBOutletCollections. Mind-boggled.

Tags: xcode, arrays, uiimage, iboutletcollection

I have 2 arrays. One is a collection of buttons. The other one should be an array of dictionaries. I am logging the length/size/count of object in the arrays in the console using [arrayListName count]:

```
2012-07-19 19:56:59.001 ABC[3224:707] lastest_badge_outlet_collection count: 4
2012-07-19 19:56:59.007 ABC[3224:707] badges_array count: 1
```

ok so when running this loop I want to populate the images with the key value 'name' from each of the dictionaries in existence in the array (that is badges_array). At the moment I have dictionary stored in that array (which is fine). However when I run this through the loop it always populates the third image along

```
for(int i = 0; i < [lastest_badge_outlet_collection count]; i++){
        UIButton *button = [lastest_badge_outlet_collection objectAtIndex:i];
        if(i < [badges_array count]){
            NSDictionary *badge_d = [badges_array objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *badge_d_image_string = [badge_d objectForKey:@"image"];
            UIImage *badge_d_image = [UIImage imageNamed: badge_d_image_string];
            [[button imageView] setImage:badge_d_image];
            [[button imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
            [button setAlpha:1.0f];
        } else {
            [button setAlpha:0.5f];
        }
    }
```

Theoretically it should be populating the first image. Why is it doing this? How does it decide which order the items are in the outlet collection for example...

Mind boggled.

I tried rewiring them to the collection 1 by 1 by wiring them up in order with no success....

Here is a screenshot.

Thanks!

[image: mindboggled]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to predict the order of IBOutletCollection.

I guess what you need to do is sort the collection before use it.

You can set `tag` property for each button and sort them by those number.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6757217/609086) answer for more detail.